# Scale Transition in Android Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I found this Scale transition on a github project. But I found it still has flaw: The view is visible from the beginning and then the animation starts from nothing to full scale. The expected result is: the view is not visible from the beginning prior to the animation.

This is the code:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public class Scale extends Visibility {
    public Scale(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public Scale() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public Animator onAppear(ViewGroup sceneRoot, View view,    TransitionValues startValues, TransitionValues endValues) {
        return createScaleAnimator(view, 0, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public Animator onDisappear(ViewGroup sceneRoot, View view, TransitionValues startValues, TransitionValues endValues) {
        return createScaleAnimator(view, 1, 0);
    }

    public Animator createScaleAnimator(View view, float startScale, float endScale) {
        PropertyValuesHolder holderX = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX", startScale, endScale);
        PropertyValuesHolder holderY = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY", startScale, endScale);
        ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(view, holderX, holderY);
        return animator;
    }
}
```

This is how to use it:

```
<transition
    class="com.jimulabs.googlemusicmock.transition.Scale"
    android:startDelay="500">
    <targets>
        <target android:targetId="@id/fab" />
    </targets>
</transition>
```

Slide transition works as expected, as it hide the view prior to the animation.

Anyone knows what's wrong the Scale class? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial scale should be set in createAnimtorScale.

```
view.setScaleX(startScale);
view.setScaleY(startScale);
```

Otherwise the initial scale doesn't start until the animator runs.